Find a table based on multiple criteria in Google sheets
I have a google sheets with thousands of table. Here is the link text
In this table I want to find a table based on two value. Such I want to find a table that is include
Fleece & NUMBER 260.
How I can find this combination from whole table?

You have multiple table with Fleece & NUMBER 260. What would be output then?

Fleece and 260 are located in different cells. I can search either Fleece or 260. If search fleece here shows all types of fleece like 260, 320, 420, 280, etc. But I only want Fleece and 260. How can I find Fleece and 260 both at a time?

This formula SCAN("",C:C,LAMBDA(a,x,IF(AND(x="Fleece",OFFSET(x,2,2)=260),ROW(x),""))) may search both at a time.

@Harun24hr This formula shows an error. Could you please add this formula to the attached sheet?

It will only find row but not full table.


Here's one approach which you may adapt accordingly:
=chooserows(A:J,sequence(7,1,xmatch(M2&N2,index(C:C&E3:E))-1,1))


UPDATED
(pull all tables that match the given criteria)
=reduce(tocol(,1),filter(sequence(rows(C1:C9997)),C1:C9997&E3:E9999=M2&N2),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,chooserows(A:K,sequence(7,1,c-1,1)),wraprows(,columns(A:K),))))



Nice. Hope it is closer to my query. Here shows only one table. Is it possible to show all the tables according to my search?

Add your expected output manually (for one test scenario) to showcase what you mean so that it gives a clear picture to us...

Ok. I added in new comments

Added updated solution

Got my answer. Is it possible to this value (X4) put in the Sub Sheet and collect data from the Main Sheet?

Sure.. Just cut the formula from X4 and paste it in a different tab. If you meant a totally different sheet altogether, then importrange() is needed

I already do it but it is cut only values, not border.

formulas do not carry-forward border or cosmetic settings!

ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION

Note: @rockinfreakshow's answer is correct. This answer is a workaround since formulas do not carry-forward border or cosmetic settings!

This method uses Google Apps Script to look for the tables with Fleece and 260 on them as well as copy the format of how they're set up in the All Price sheet with copyFormatToRange(sheet, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd).
Assuming that every table uses 7 rows and 10 columns with a single space in between, you may also use this sample script to achieve what you'd like to do:

I have also added some explanations of what the code does

const myFunction = () => {
  // Gets your current active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // Gets the spreadsheet named "All Price"
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("All Price");
  // Gets the spreadsheet named "Sheet43"
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet43");
  // Declaration of the range to be used in the spreadsheet
  var rg = sh1.getRange(1, 1, sh1.getLastRow(), 14);
  // Gets the values of the declared range
  var vl = rg.getValues();
  // Empty array
  var dt = [];
  // Loops through the data in groups of 8
  for (var i = 0; i < vl.length; i += 8) {
    dt.push(vl.slice(i, i + 8));
  }
  // Empty array
  var op = [];
  // Searches for "Fleece" or "FLEECE" in the data and adds it to the op variable
  for (var i = 0; i < dt.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < dt[i].length; j++) {
      for (var k = 0; k < dt[i][j].length; k++) {
        dt[i][j][k] == "Fleece" || "FLEECE" ? op.push(dt[i]) : null;
      }
    }
  }
  // Filtered data containing '"Fleece" and 260
  var fd = op.filter(d => d.some(r => r.includes(260))).flat();
  // Clears the data in "Sheet43"
  sh2.clear();
  // Sets the values of the tables found
  sh2.getRange(1, 1, fd.length, fd[0].length).setValues(fd);
  // Copies the format of the tables in "All Price" and pastes them in "Sheet43"
  rg.copyFormatToRange(sh2, 1, 14, 1, fd.length);
}


Make sure to go to Extensions > Apps Script on the spreadsheet and run the code from there.

OUTPUT


Selecting all the data and resizing any of the columns after will result in the following:


